# Pass attribute name of class as parameter in function

Tags: python, function, class

So I have a class like this:

```
class var:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

object = var(1, 2, 3)
```

And I want to make a function that takes as a parameter the name of one of the attributes of my class, to make something like this (example):

```
def function(object, a):
    object.a = 5
```

Obviously I can pass 'a' as a string and make some if cases:

```
def function(object, a):

    if (a == 'x'):
        object.x = 5

    if (a == 'y'):
        object.y = 5

    if (a == 'z'):
        object.z = 5
```

But in that case I'd have to copy the entire code inside the if's (obviously I want to do more than just assign a value). I'd like to know if there's a clever way to do that.

edit:

To clarify, my object has more variables:

```
class var:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, a, b, c):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

And I will access these in my functions. That's why i don't pass simply object.x or object.y. I will pass the object and the variable I will use, but there are other variables I will access.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't simply pass `object.a` as a single parameter, rather than `object` and `a` as two separate parameters?

Comment: @BryanOakley the OP wants to set the value of *any* attribute of the object, which *I think* will not be achieved by passing in `object.a`

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: well, you can pass any attribute you want: `function(object.a)`, `function(object.b)` etc. Whatever you pass in is what gets set.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not entirely sure what you mean. Once the value is passed, how can you change the attribute in the object *through* that value, especially when the attribute is of primitive types like `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `setattr`:

```
def set(object, name):
    setattr(object, name, 5)
```

Comment: This might create unwanted new variables for the object. e.g. set(object, 'm')  will assign a new variable to the object i.e. object.m

Comment: You can consider adding a check `if name in object.__dict__:` before calling setattr on the object.

Comment: @Afaq or you can also use `hasattr()` method.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes I agree with you, but what if the class contains a method with name `test`, then in that case `hasattr(object, 'test')` will return true and render `test` method useless after `setattr`. `object.__dict__` will just contain the instance variables.

Comment: @Afaq yeah, that's right. Thanks for pointing that out. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Extending what Daniel showed in his answer, you can first check if the object has the attribute or not by using [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr), and then set the value of the attribute by using [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
def function(object, a):
    if name in object.__dict__:
        setattr(object, a, 5)
```

Note: take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330143/pass-variable-of-class-as-parameter-in-function#comment71813422_42330176), which showed the correct way to determine if an object has an attribute. What I mean is `__dict__` doesn't include method names.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted.